# Class selector containing a Percent sign SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have the following class `.\40-85%-shares-key` that I need to be able to use in my stylesheet but I can't figure out how to escape the first digit with unicode in order to get it to work.

I've tried this:

```
.\0034 0-85%-shares-key {}
```

But no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The percent sign is a special character in Sass:  it means that it is a placeholder selector.  Placeholder selectors are not found in the final CSS.

Generally speaking, you should avoid using special characters like the percent sign in your selectors.  If you really need to, you can escape it with a backslash:

```
.\0034 0-60\%-shares-key { color: red; }
```

Now it is valid in both Sass and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I could get this to work was with the CSS3 ends-with selector `$=`:

```
[class$="40-85%-shares-key"] { color:red }
```

This will fail if there is a second class added after `.\40-85%-shares-key`.

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ro3mrtzw/**

I would greatly recommend changing the format to something like `.shares-key-40-to-85` because it's invalid CSS to have special characters like `\` and `%` in class names (and therefore browsers will be unreliable)